# Upgrade Trusted Platform Module (TPM)?

Tags: hardware, bitlocker, tpm

I have some systems that I am unable to enable Bitlocker on. The TPM wizard reports that the version of the TPM is inadequate to function with bitlocker.

Is it possible to upgrade a TPM to 1.2?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Check with your vendor to see if there are any firmware updates. Most computers have the TPM module built in, so it's not replaceable/upgradeable, but some do have modules that can be upgraded.